# "Could not find a part of the path" Error For File Read Operation in Azure App

Tags: c#, azure, azure-web-app-service, asp.net-core-1.1, azure-app-api

I built an ASP.NET Core api application it is deployed to Azure web api app. 
In the code, I try at some point to read the contents of a file in content root, interpolating certain place holders for their actual values.

Now on my local system this works just fine cause it is able to get the exact file path of the file but in the cloud, I get an exception with the following message:

> Could not find a part of the path...

I get the full file path like so:

```
Path.Combine(hostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath, "containing directory\filename")
```

But this fails in the cloud. Are there extras I should know about deploying this or what am I doing wrong with respect to understanding directory structuring in cloud deployment?

N.B
I could store this file in an Azure file storage container but I feel it will be too much hassle to read it plus the cost seeing this file will be read quite often.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Could not find a part of the path...

According to the exception, it indicates that there is no related path in the Azure. If it is possible, we could [remote debug Azure Web Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-dotnet-troubleshoot-visual-studio#remotedebug). Then we could get the file path. After that we could use the Azure kudu(https://yoursite.scm.azurewebsites.net) tool to check whether the path is existing.

[image]

If the file path is not existing, we could drag the folder to kudu tool directly or we also could publish the folder with Visual Studio. After that it should work.

[image]

We could get more info about  [Azure Web App sandbox](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox). About Azure website file structure please refer the [document](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/File-structure-on-azure)

```
/
    LogFiles
        Application
            <instance>-<pid>-<ticks>.txt // application (nodejs/dotnet/php) traces
        DetailedError
            ErrorPage####.htm // error details
        Git
            trace
                trace.xml // Trace generated during git deployments
                <instance>-<guid>.txt // kudu related traces
            deployment
                <instance>-<guid>.txt // deployment related traces
        http
            RawLogs
                <logfile>.log     // iis http log. iis buffers and flushes every 60sec.
        W3SVC#####
            fr####.xml            // IIS fail request traces
            freb.xsl
    site
        wwwroot
            hello.htm             // The files that are live in your app
        repository                // Your repo, including working files (i.e. not bare)
            .git
                HEAD, index and other git files
        deployments
            [commit id 1]
                log.xml           // The deployment log, similar to what the protal shows
                status.xml        // The status of the deployment (success/failure)
                manifest          // The list of files that were deployed
            [commit id 2]
                ...
    .ssh
        config                // This contains config to disable strict host checking
        id_rsa                // private key in PEM format
        known_hosts           // known hosts have been accepted
    Data
        Jobs
            Triggered
                MyTriggeredJob1
                    20131112101559
                        output.log
                        error.log
                        status

            Continuous
                MyContinuousJob1
                    job.log
                    status
    SiteExtensions
        // TODO: add details here
```

Comment: Very detailed answer that helped highlight and fill other gaping holes in my knowledge base. I resorted to Azure file share but implementing some of the things suggested here helped a billion towards achieving exactly what I wanted!